# How to redirect to other view after authentication

Tags: php, angularjs, mysqli, ionic-framework

I m working on authentification in my application, with AngularJS and PHP backend, in controller I put a console.log, to see if the authentication is working, and I find that everything is alright, when the password and username are incorrect I get error message and when they are wrong , I get that they are incorrect, but in that case, I want to be redirected to other view , when I put : window.location.href = '#/admin'; it redirect me to admin view in the two cases, not only when they are correct. can you help me please:

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $location,$state,$http,$window){

    $scope.submit = function()
        {
          data = {
            'NomClient' : $scope.NomClient,
            'mdp' : $scope.mdp
        };

        $http.post('http://localhost/deb/login.php', data)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config,result)
        {    
            console.log(data);

            window.location.href = '#/admin';
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config, rsult)
        {    
        console.log('error');

        });
    }

});
```

login.php

```
 <?php  

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sem1");  


 if(count($data) > 0)  
 { 
$NomClient=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->NomClient);
$mdp=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->mdp);


$query = 'SELECT * FROM `client` WHERE NomClient = "'.$NomClient.'" AND   mdp= "'.$mdp.'"';

$q = mysqli_query($connect , $query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0 )
  { 
       $_SESSION["logged_in"] = true; 
       $_SESSION["naam"] = $NomClient; 
       $result['code'] = 200;
       $result['message'] ='Logged In';
  }
  else
  {

       $result['code'] = 603;
       $result['message'] ='The username or password are incorrect!';
  }

$resultstring = json_encode($result);
$resultstring = str_replace("null",'""',$resultstring);
echo $resultstring ;
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `window.location.href` use

```
$state.go(state_name_of_#/admin)
```

Refer this [$state.go()](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options)

The success function calls always when there is response irrespective of authentication.

in your PHP file, return true response only if the authentication success, otherwise return false to the front end

Then check for the `response` or `response.responseMessage` in something you will find the returned value.

```
.success(function(reponse){
    var data = JSON.parse(reponse);
    if(data.code == 200){
       $state.go(enter_your_state_name_of_admin); // example "admin"
    } else {
       // do nothing
    }
})
```

Comment: I tried this solution, but I still have the same problem, Im always redirected however the password is wrong

Comment: Check for updated solution, now. Any how you will get response

Comment: I update my wuestion and I ve puted login.php file, how can I return true only if the authentication success please!

Comment: Please print this and tell me the results? `echo $resultstring ;`

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean please! I already had "echo $resultstring'

Comment: I mean what is the value of `$resultstring`? Yeah, what it shows in the browser/console?

Comment: In the console, when  the password and username are correct, I get result: logged in, and code 200, and when I put a wrong password , I get result: The username or password are incorrect! with code 603

Comment: Now, try the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$state.go()` for this as:
`$state.go('admin');`

'admin must be your state name.'

**EDIT**

The code in `.success` will be executed when ever you get data without any error. If you want to redirect based on the authentication, you need to write code for that seperately. Example code is given below.

```
.success(function(data, status, headers, config,result) {    
    console.log(data);
    if(data.message === 'Logged In') {
      $state.go('admin');
    }
})
```

Comment: I tried this solution, but I still have the same problem, Im always redirected however the password is wrong

Comment: but AUTHENTICATED  is not definded, what should I put in this condition!

Comment: What `data` prints in `console`?

Comment: In the console, when the password and username are correct, I get result: logged in, and code 200, and when I put a wrong password , I get result: The username or password are incorrect! with code 603

Comment: Updated the answer. Once check it.

Comment: I tried the solution of Mr_Perfect and it s working, and also yours , but he was the first, Thank you so much , Thanks a lot